# Silverlight 3 debugging issue and intellesense issue

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I am pretty new to Silverlight 3.0.

I have installed **Silverlight 3 Developer** on Visual Studio 2008 SP1; and later on I came to know that I have to install **Silverlight3_Tools.exe**.

Hence, I have uninstalled **Silverlight Developer** and installed **Silverlight3_Tools.exe**.

From then onwards I am facing lot of problems with Silverlight in my development box.

**The most killing problems are these two below**

- Whenever I run the application in Debug mode I get the following error:

**Unable to start debugging. The Silverlight managed debugging package isn't installed.**

- While working with code editor in Silverlight, intellesence is not working. Whatever the installation I have done (VS-2008SP1 and Silverlight3_Tools.exe) I have given the same to colleagues. Everything is working fine for them.

Hence, above two problems are killing me and stopping me to go ahead.

Can anybody please help me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to double click on **Silverlight3_Toos.exe** file to install.

But; for some reason, I guess installation was not happened and all files are simply getting copied into hard-drive. Why because I found that there is **NO** registry writing during installation. I came to this conclusion only after I found this [great resource](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/17651.aspx/3/10).

Hence, I have uninstalled everything and restarted the system with the intension to reinstall once again.
I have done like below since I am working on **Windows XP with SP3**.

•   Right click on **Silverlight3_Tools.exe** and select **Run as...** from the context menu.

•   Choose Administrator access and Run the file.

Now, the installation was successfully completed.

Thanks and Regards,

Ashok kumar.